# using lift-json for parsing in scala in SBT

Tags: json, scala, parsing, sbt, lift-json

I am trying to use lift-json to parse json. Have been to this link https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/ and as suggested have added `val lift_json = "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.9"` to "built.sbt". "import net.liftweb.json._" still throws the error

`object liftweb is not a member of package net`.

How can I begin using lift-json?

Comment: Have you successfully resolved dependencies ?

Comment: yes, the dependencies have been resolved. sbt package runs successfully.

Comment: then what's the error ?

Comment: object liftweb is not a member of package net

Comment: Oh!! sorry. sbt package is throwing error.scala:13: object liftweb is not a member of package net
[error] import net.liftweb.json._

Comment: could you share your build file ? Is it possible that the dependency get evicted by newer versions ?